# Resolving: Fatal error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\AddressFormatRepository'

Tags: commerce

The Address module was installed using the [Ludwig](https://www.drupal.org/project/ludwig) module. I tried to update the module, but I cannot, as the site gives me this error and the site install has not been done via Composer.

Everything was working fine until an unrelated module was installed.

The error message I get is the following.

> Fatal error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\AddressFormatRepository' not found in \modules\contrib\address\src\Repository\AddressFormatRepository.php on line 16

Most information I found involves using Composer to resolve the issue, but the site is not using Composer.

UPDATE: If anyone stumbles across this, I resolved the issue by Composerising the website. I followed [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal/add-composer-to-an-existing-site), then updated all modules, including Address, using Composer. I previously thought I wouldn't be able to composerise the website due to the error but I was wrong. Hopefully that helps someone.

Comment: I don't know what Ludwig is. I think many others also don't know. What happens when you uninstall and remove the Address module again? Does the error persist? You need to do the debugging yourself. No one else has access to your site and environment. All we can do is wild guessing. Which is too broad for a Q&A format like Drupal Answers. Consider updating your question to make it actually reproducible or maybe ask on Drupal Slack in the #support channel and hope someone there can give you some suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! How to update Ludwig managed modules is described in [Maintenance of Ludwig managed modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/ludwig/maintenance-of-ludwig-managed-modules). Did you follow those instructions?

Comment: Probably either file an issue with Ludwig or read its docs - a majority of people will just say to use Composer because that is the standard.

Comment: @leymannx Ludwig is a module initially created for installing the "Address" module without using composer. I cannot uninstall the address module because the site has this error message preventing me from accessing anything.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've read those instructions but the site gives me this error message preventing me from using it. So I can't perform any actions using the Drupal website interface. I have tried clearing the cache manually (emptying cache database tables). I have tried deleting the address folder. I have tried redownloading the original address folder and also newer versions.

Comment: @Kevin I want to composerise this website but I need to get it working first. This error message is completely blocking the website.